# adding time interval to a column in dataframe spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Below is my dataframe.

```
    import spark.implicits._
    val lastRunDtDF = sc.parallelize(Seq(
                                (1, 2,"2019-07-18 13:34:24") 
                                )).toDF("id", "cnt","run_date")

    lastRunDtDF.show

    +---+---+-------------------+
    | id|cnt|           run_date|
    +---+---+-------------------+
    |  1|  2|2019-07-18 13:34:24|
    +---+---+-------------------+
```

I want to create a new dataframe with a new column as new_run_date by adding 2 minutes to the existing run_date column. sample Output like below.

```
    +---+---+-------------------+-------------------+
    | id|cnt|           run_date|       new_run_date|
    +---+---+-------------------+-------------------+
    |  1|  2|2019-07-18 13:34:24|2019-07-18 13:36:24|
    +---+---+-------------------+-------------------+
```

I am trying something like below

```
  lastRunDtDF.withColumn("new_run_date",lastRunDtDF("run_date")+"INTERVAL 2 MINUTE")
```

Looks like its not the right way. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping `INTERVAL 2 MINUTE` in **`expr`** function.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr
lastRunDtDF.withColumn("new_run_date",lastRunDtDF("run_date") + expr("INTERVAL 2 MINUTE"))
           .show()
```

***Result:***

```
+---+---+-------------------+-------------------+
| id|cnt|           run_date|       new_run_date|
+---+---+-------------------+-------------------+
|  1|  2|2019-07-18 13:34:24|2019-07-18 13:36:24|
+---+---+-------------------+-------------------+
```

(or)

***By using from_unixtime,unix_timestamp functions:***

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

lastRunDtDF.selectExpr("*","from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(run_date) + 2*60,
                            'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as new_run_date")
           .show()
```

**Result:**

```
+---+---+-------------------+-------------------+
| id|cnt|           run_date|       new_run_date|
+---+---+-------------------+-------------------+
|  1|  2|2019-07-18 13:34:24|2019-07-18 13:36:24|
+---+---+-------------------+-------------------+
```